# multiles .py in same directory do affect the python command?

Tags: python, directory, python-requests

I was testing the script (wcrawler.py):

```
import requests
```

and getting errors:

```
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 90, in <module>
        import textwrap
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
        class TextWrapper:
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
        whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

so I just changed the others scripts to another directory and used the same command: python wcrawler.py

worth, I don't have idea why, do you know anything about it?

Comment: Is that the *only* line in your script? Also, please post the **full text** of the traceback.

Comment: You most likely have a script named string.py somewhere in your path which textwrap is importing from instead of the actual string lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You most likely have a script named string.py somewhere in your path
>   which textwrap is importing from instead of the actual string lib –
>   Padraic Cunningham

was just that!